# Auto scale rule based on custom CloudWatch alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an auto-scaling group of EC2 servers that run a number of processes. This number of processes changes with the load and I'd like to trigger a scaling (up/down) based on the number of processes.

I've successfully set up a script that sends to CloudWatch the number of processes on every servers, for every minutes, and I can see these on CloudWatch. (I haven't set a dimension, to be able to get the value for all the servers).

Then, I created an Alarm, that uses the average for the values sent, and if it reach a certain limit, it triggers the "Add a new server" to the auto scaling group, and when it stop being on alarm, it triggers a "Remove a server".

My issue is that when I add the new server, the average drops, since there is one more server now, which move the alarm to the OK state, removing the server, and increasing again the average, triggering again the alarm, etc.

For instance, the limit is set to 10 processes on average. With 3 servers, if the average becomes 11, I trigger the alarm state, adding a server. Now with the new server, I'm at 33 processes (3 x 11) for 4 servers : 8,25 processes on average, thus triggering the "OK" alarm.

**My question is**: Is it possible to set up an alarm based on the number of processes without having the new trigger causes a up-down-up-down issue?

Instead of average, I can use something else to trigger the alarm, such as min/max/I-don't-know.

Comment: How are the processes distributed amongst the instances? How do you ensure that each server runs an equal number of processes? Are they pulling work from a queue? What is the limiting factor you are wanting to overcome -- CPU, Memory? What happens if an instance runs more than 10 processes? It sounds like you could simply use [Target tracking scaling policies for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html), but it would be helpful to understand your situation more.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The EC2 instances are behind a ELB. I haven't configured the ELB directly (it was done via Beanstalk) but I suspect that it distributes the requests equally amongst the servers. I can't ensure that each servers run an equal number of processes, and if they reach higher than the limit, that's kind of ok as long as it's not too high (that's the idea behind launching another server when I reach the limit). The processes are launched from an incoming HTTP request from the main server. Hope that answers your questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* create an alarm that adds instances when True and removes instances when False. This will cause a continual 'flip-flop' situation rather than trying to find a steady-state.

You could have each server regularly send a custom metric to Amazon CloudWatch. You could then use this with [Target tracking scaling policies for Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html), which will calculate the **average value** of the metric and automatically launch/terminate instances to keep the target value around 10.

This would work well with long-running processes (perhaps 5+ minutes with several processes running concurrently), but would not be good with short sub-minute processes because it takes time to launch new instances.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into that. The processes are a conversions system that can takes between a few seconds, up to 10 minutes, depending on the content to convert. Do you have any specific recommendations about "sub-minutes processes"?

Comment: So, here's what I did. I created two alarms, one "High demand" that is above the threshold (of 10), and a "Low demand" (when lower than 8). Then I created two "Simple scaling" dynamic scaling policies, based on these two alarms. When "High" is in "Alarm state" it will add one instance. When "Low" is in alarm state, it will remove one instance. I've also added a "wait period" for both, to give enough time for the servers to pick up the pace. What do you think?

Comment: Also this makes me wonder, does the configuration I've done enables the service to add more than one instance (like an increasing workload)? Or once the alarm has been triggered once, it won't again? The idea is that since the "low" alarm is lower than the expected threshold (8 instead of 10), adding a new instance could drop to 8, then 9, causing the high alarm to go off, but not trigger the low alarm (of 8). Then if it continues to grow to 10 and higher, this "high" alarm would trigger again. Am I correct on this assumption?

Comment: Yes. It can be tricky to configure scaling policies and alarms to have it react as expected. Increasing the "wait period" will prevent a quick succession of adding and removing instances. The number of instances will grow and shrink within the `Min` and `Max` range you have configured on the Auto Scaling group.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented these yesterday, and so far, I got two scaling up then down that seems to have been handled properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could look at [metric math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html). So instead of directly triggering your alarm based on your process-count-metric only, you could perhabs calculate the average count yourself using  metric math. You could use the `GroupTotalInstances` metric from your ASG, or just publish second custom metric having the number of instances.

In both cases, your metric for the alarm would use metric math to divide number of processes by size of ASG for each evaluation period.